# NGINX URL Redirection

Tags: nginx, redirect, url

In nginx we have been trying to redirect a URL as follows:
Client hits the url: https://new.domain.com/reg?account.name=ABC&accountID.number=1234&OrderNumber=11111111&Code=2222

and nginx has to route the request to the back-end tomcat.

http://localhost:8000/some_dir/reg?account.name=ABC&accountID.number=1234&OrderNumber=11111111&Code=2222.

server configuration as follows:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name localhost;

location ~ ^/reg?(.*) {
            resolver x.x.x.x;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/some_dir/reg?$1;
}
```

With the above settings I could able to see the requests are hitting the back-end tomcat while accessing from browser. But, URI strings after "reg?" ie.:`"account.name=ABC&accountID.number=1234&OrderNumber=11111111&Code=2222"` aren't getting directed.

Can someone help me point out whats wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `location` matches only the path component of a URL. So, as written, your regex matches many more URLs than you expect. For instance, it matches `/re`, `/redwood`, `/regular` as well as `/reg`. But it *does not* put the query string in the capture, because the query string is not part of the path component.

Fortunately, you don't need a regex at all, nor do you need to capture the query string, as nginx already keeps track of it. Consider:

```
location /reg {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/some_dir/reg$is_args$args;
}
```

Here we get rid of all the extraneous matches and match only URL paths beginning with `/reg`. You can make it more specific by using `location = /reg` instead. Then we pass the arguments explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Michael, This really helped. Is there way to preserve the images

Comment: I don't understand your question. What images do you want to preserve?

Comment: Thanks Michael, This really helped. However, i see the images and URL banners were missing with misplaced input text box after redirection.  Is there way to preserve the images and text box alignments.

Comment: That's a different problem though. You should check your nginx error logs and see why the images are not being served. But I guess you haven't set a `root` for serving static files.

Comment: Error file is complaining about missing required gif & js files under /etc/nginx/html/registration-ui/xxxx/ab/information.js. You are right. no root has been set to server static files. Is there any quick reference guide to read and set up the root parameters ?

Comment: I'm able to complete my setup with root directive and things has moved as expected in happy path. Thanks for your inputs.